# Proof that the minimum of a bounded differentiable real function occurs at a stationary point or at an endpoint

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

I couldn't find a proof for this well-known result on this site...

> The minimum of a bounded differentiable real function occurs at a stationary point or at an endpoint.

I prove the contrapositive to this statement in my answer below.

Alternative proofs are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain is unbounded, say $(0,+\infty)$, then the question needs some clarification as the minimum of $x\to1/x$ is not attained.

If the domain is bounded, say $[0,1]$, the minimum exists by continuity of $f$ and a consequence of Bolzano-Weierstrass ("the image of a segment by a continuous function is a segment"). Let $c\in[0,1]$ be the point where the minimum is attained. If $c\notin\{0,1\}$, we look at
$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
which is always non-negative if $x>c$ as $f(x)\ge f(c)$ holds. This proves that the limit $\lim_{x\to c^+}$ of the above quotient is non-negative. Similarly by looking at $x<c$, we see that $\lim_{x\to c^-}$ of the the above quotient is non-positive. Hence the limit is both non-positive and non-negative, i.e., $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: I'm not aware of the version of Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem that says that "the image of a segment by a continuous function is a segment". B-W is about sequential compactness. However, it is true that the continuous mapping of a compact set is compact. e.g. see Rudin PMA Theorem $4.14$. I'm just not sure that's what B-W is about.

Comment: All these are pretty much 2 lines proofs after BW. The image of $[0,1]$ by a continuous function is bounded, otherwise for any $n$, there exists $x_n$ with $f(x_n)<-n$ and a converging subsequence $x_{g(n)}$ with $f(x_{g(n)})$ having a limit by continuity: contradiction. Similarly the infimum is attained, by BW, by extracting a converging subsequence from a sequence $x_n$ satisfying $f(x_n)\ge \inf f - 1/n$.

Comment: Typo: the last equation should read $f(x_n)\le \inf f +1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable real function, and suppose that $c \in [0,1]$ is neither a stationary point nor an endpoint, but $c$ is a minimum. Then $f'(c)$ exists because $f$ is differentiable, but $f'(c)=\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\neq 0,\ $ because $c$ is not a stationary point. Suppose WLOG that $f'(c)>0$. Then since $c$ is not the left endpoint, namely $0, $ and since $f'(c)>0, \ \exists k\ $ with $\ 0<k<c$ such that $f(k)<f(c)$, contradicting the minimality of $c$.

Admittedly I didn't prove the last line very formally, although I'm not sure how to, to be honest.